# How to get value outside onclick function after redirection to other page

Tags: jquery

I have a click function that determines what attribute clicked, it saves the value into variable `sect` and after it redirects to other page and I want to use this value outside of the function, How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
    $(".image-portfolio").on('click', function(){
          var sect = $(this).attr("data-section");
          window.location = "portfolio.html";

    });

alert(sect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can create `cookie` and store value of variable and once you move to another page get that value back.

Or another way is you can store value in `browsers(local) storage` area and retrieve back.

**Store value in local storage**

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "John Doe");
```

**Retrieve value from local storage**

```
localStorage.getItem("name");
```

This will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot!! used localstorage and it works perfectly

Comment: The beauty of local storage is you can use this value in any page.

Answer (score 1):

After you change the page, your script files are wiped and reloaded.

If you're just trying to pass an album name or something like this (data which is not sensitive) you could pass this in the url and retrieve the query parameter after.

```
$(".image-portfolio").on('click', function(){
          var sect = $(this).attr("data-section");
          window.location = "portfolio.html?album="+sect;
});
```

Then on your other page do

```
var sect = $.url().param('album');
```

This is only an example to get you started. You might need to apply extra code and tweaking however this is a basic and sample idea how to pass non-sensitive data across pages using URL.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value outside the function you should declare the variable globally like below

```
var sect; //global declaration

 $(".image-portfolio").on('click', function(){
          sect = $(this).attr("data-section");
         // window.location = "portfolio.html";

    });

alert(sect);
```

if you redirect to another page that doesn't make any sense to alert the value;

if you want to just redirect without alert then you can get the value on another page you can use @Adriani6's answer as

```
$(".image-portfolio").on('click', function(){
          var sect = $(this).attr("data-section");
          window.location = "portfolio.html?album="+sect;
});
```

and on portfolio.html

```
var sect = $.url().param('album');
```